# Problem to deploy ASP.NET Core 6 Web API site

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm having a problem with deploying an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API on a Windows 2016 server. Once I deploy my site I get a 500.30 error indicating an "*ASP. NET Core app failed to start*" (see screenshot).

To verify that this was not due to my server configuration I deployed an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app and I have no problem; the site works perfectly and I can access the different pages.

I don't understand why my API site doesn't work. I tried to deploy it on another server with the same configuration and it works perfectly.
Below are the parameters of my project and the elements installed on the server.

- Project: ASP.NET Core 6 Web API
- Windows server :

  - .NET 6.0.12 - Windows Server Hosting
  - Microsoft .NET Runtime 6.0.12 (x84 & x64)

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the Event Viewer logs on that Windows server? What do they tell you?

Comment: Have you tried a self contained deploy? You should be able to `dotnet run` the app off the server.

Comment: Try "Step 3" from [this page](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/07/16/7-tips-for-troubleshooting-asp-net-core-startup-errors.aspx).

Comment: @marc_s

I just looked at the Event Viewer logs have that Windows server and I have an error related to my site.
In searching many comments indicated that the best thing to do was to re-deploy and restart the server. That's what I did and it seems to have worked as my APIs are now properly accessible.